# How can I merge the code from two programs?

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino-uno

I've been working on some programming code which I already have. It is a device which measures weight(load cell). I have bought a Load Cell Display Unit which already has a program on it. But the problem is I need two of those and I do no know how I am going to merge the code and readjust the variables. My goal is to ADD the results from the two load cells. I am using an Arduino Uno board which only has one RX and TX pins that is why I connected the other TX and RX to D2 and D3 of the arduino.

```
*/
Connections:
LDU1 to Arduino board
TX1  =  D0
RX1  =  D1
GND1 =  GND

LDU2 to Arduino board
TX2  =  D2
RX2  =  D3
GND2 =  GND

VIN =  7-9VDC /VIN
*/

// defines used by the serial event
// do not modify
#define  STX 2
#define  ETX 3
#define  SERIALSTX 0
#define  SERIALETX 1
#define  SERIALRDY 2

This is a part of the code. I do not know how I am going to define the D2 and D3 pins as TX2 and RX2.
```

Comment: Sorry, but we're too cold on this site :) (for formalities)

Comment: @kim366 Could you explain your comment? I cannot see a relation of this question to either temperature or etiquette.

Comment: When you used your favorite search engine, did you notice https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive ? It seems that using more than one serial connection on Arduino is non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch that helped a lot. Can I also asked about the reassignment of other variables? Lets say on this part:

        `// Weight read results
        String  temp_value;      // data streaming
 
         byte  serial_state;
         String serialinput;`

How am I going to get the value for the second string? Should I write it like this:
         `String  temp_value2;      // data streaming
           byte  serial_state2;
           String serialinput2;`

Comment: I am sorry. I have watched some tutorial but I guess it's not enough to know more about programming. I have limited knowledge about it. Thank you again!

Comment: I do not get what you are asking in your comment. It should however be a separate question no matter what.

Comment: @Yunnosch Look at my edit, which got approved